# Build a (custom) module in Odoo OpenERP

Tags: module, odoo, openerp-7

I have downloaded the source code of Odoo (previously OpenERP) and installed OpenERP. I wanted to know how can I create new module, build it and install it (on Windows) when I don't have the Update Module List.

Comment: Did you look for this information on the Internet and more specifically on Odoo.com ?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I don't know where do i have to create my module

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET what about giving him the link to the page? Would have cost you less keystrokes about something unhelpful.

Comment: @javidazac look at Mischievous's answer. That's the page you need.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this doc. This is in new api version 8.0

[Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html)

Answer (score 3):

To build an Odoo module please Have a look [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html) Which is the Basic Odoo Documentation to builds a new addon. To update Apps list after building the addon after restarting the server you have to follow below methods according to the versions so that you can [customize](https://www.cybrosys.com/odoo-customization-and-installation/) it.

1. Odoo V8

   Go to settings -> Users -> Check the Technical Features.
   Update Apps list and Install custom add-on.
2. Odoo V9

   [image: odoo9] click on About, will open wizard

   [image] Use active developer mode and then Update Apps list and Install custom add-on.
3. Odoo V10

   [image: 10] Goto Settings -> Activate developer mode and then Update Apps list and Install custom add-on.

After Updating the module list you can see the custom add-on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all place your module into addon folder of your odoo installation

1. Log in as Administrator
2. got to settings - users - Administrator
3. click on Edit
4. Check Technical properties
5. Save and refresh your browser
6. Go to Settings - Modules - Refresh module list
7. Click on Refresh

If everything went well you will see your own module within the list

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have technical features enabled for your user in the access rights section.

Once you have enabled it, logout and login again and you should see Update Module List menu item

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of first importance put your module into addon envelope of your odoo establishment

When you have empowered it, logout and login again and you ought to see Update Module List menu thing. An other way to [odoo erp customization](http://techloyce.com/our-services/odoo/)

Sign in as Administrator

got to settings - clients - Administrator

tap on Edit

Check Technical properties

Spare and invigorate your program

Go to Settings - Modules - Refresh module list